# How to power Raspberry Pi from a lab power supply via USB?

Tags: usb, power, power-supply, connectors

How can a Raspberry Pi be powered from a lab power supply via USB?

I have a lab power supply that can easily output 5 V/4 A and I would like
to use it to power a Raspberry Pi (version 3B and 3B+).

In theory one could attach the power directly to the +5v pin in the header, but that means bypassing the over-current and over-voltage protection provided by the USB circuitry. Thus I would like to use the USB port.

**Is it enough to wire the positive and negative rails of the lab power supply to the +/- pins of a male micro USB connector?**

Should the data pins be left unconnected/floating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should work.  The data pins are not connected at the Pi end of the microUSB socket, the socket is purely for power.